# VueJs: problem with deep selector on hover element

Tags: vue.js, vue-script-setup

I want to do a carousel of images, in which the active element shows a text inside itself when it's hovered.

A part of my HTML/css that define my carousel:

```
    <div id="crsl" class="mt-5" v-if="imageList.length > 0">
      <div v-for="image in imageList" ref="divList" class="crsl-item " >
        <Image :id="image.id" :sized="false"></Image>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
<style scoped>
.firstprv , .lastprv , .act , .firstnxt, .lastnxt  {
  display: block !important;
  max-height:fit-content;
}

.firstprv, .firstnxt{
 width : 15%;
 opacity: 80%;
}

.lastprv,.lastnxt{
 width: 10%;
 opacity: 70%;
}

.firstprv:hover, .lastprv:hover, .lastnxt:hover,.firstnxt:hover{
  opacity: 90%;
}

.lastprv{
  order:1;
}

.firstprv{
  order:2;
}

.firstnxt{
  order:4;
}

.lastnxt{
  order:5;
}
.act {
  width: 30%;  
  order: 3;
}
```

In my script setup, I initialize that carousel by adding classes to carousel items. I append a p element to the active crsl-item of the carousel :

```
const p = document.createElement("P");
p.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0; background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72); color: #fff; visibility: hidden;  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;");
p.innerText = "Edit";

function setCarousel(i: number){
  clearCarousel();
  const list = divList.value;
  const length = list.length;
  index.value = i;
  var active = list[i];
  active.classList.add("act");
  active.appendChild(p);
  list[modulo(i+1,length)].classList.add("firstnxt");
  list[modulo(i-1,length)].classList.add("firstprv");
  list[modulo(i+2,length)].classList.add("lastnxt");
  list[modulo(i-2,length)].classList.add("lastprv");
}
```

All of these codes work. My problem is when I want that p element to change its opacity from 0 to 1 when the active item of the carousel is hovered. To do that, I put this in my css code :

```
.act:deep(p) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.act:hover:deep(p){
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

[The first selector actually works,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7IIJ.png)
but the second one doesn't, it don't change the opacity when the active item is hovered.

Thank you for reading this and I hope that someone could help me with that !